# Vector.clear() in Multidimensional Vectors

Tags: java, eclipse, vector

I was making a program to read and convert text files into a 2D vector of custom objects in eclipse, but it seems that whenever I call Vector.clear() on the 1D vector, it also deletes the respective element in the 2D vector. Why is this happening and how do I fix this? Also, please keep in mind I am a beginner in java.

```
    public Vector<Vector<gridObject>> copyToVector(Scanner s){
    //main instantiation
    Scanner lineReader = null;
    gridObject objectInstance = new gridObject();
    objectInstance.w = 10;
    objectInstance.h = 10;
    Vector<gridObject> objectVector = new Vector<gridObject>();
    Vector<Vector<gridObject>> objectMatrix = new Vector<Vector<gridObject>>();
    int rowNumber = 0;
    int columnNumber = 0;
    //reads next line break
    while(s.hasNextLine()){
        lineReader = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
        rowNumber++;
        //reads next character
        while(lineReader.hasNext()){
            columnNumber++;
            //decides what object the character represents
            switch(lineReader.next()){
                case "0":
                    objectInstance.x = 10*(columnNumber-1);
                    objectInstance.y = 10*(rowNumber - 1);
                    objectInstance.id = 0;
                    break;
                case "1":
                    objectInstance.x = 10*(columnNumber-1);
                    objectInstance.y = 10*(rowNumber - 1);
                    objectInstance.id = 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    objectInstance.x = 10*(columnNumber-1);
                    objectInstance.y = 10*(rowNumber - 1);
                    objectInstance.id = -1;
                    break;
            }
            objectVector.addElement(objectInstance);
        }
        objectMatrix.addElement(objectVector);
        System.out.println(objectMatrix.elementAt(0).size());
        objectVector.clear();
        System.out.println(objectMatrix.elementAt(0).size());
        columnNumber = 0;
    }
    lineReader.close();
    return objectMatrix;
}
```

The file this function is reading is  a simple txt file composed of 0s

```
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And the output is this:

```
    10
    0
    10
    0
    10
    0
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: "whenever I call Vector.clear() on the 1D vector, it also deletes the respective element in the 2D vector" Just based on this, I'm betting it's because you're keeping a reference to the 1D vector around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
objectVector.clear()
```

with

```
objectVector = new Vector<gridObject>();
```

As you are already adding the objectVector to the objectMatrix calling clear on the same instance will clear within matrix as well. A new reference is required to put new values.

Also right after the following line

```
objectVector.addElement(objectInstance);
```

Add  a new line

```
objectInstance = new gridObject();
```

objectInstance should be different for values each time within the program otherwise it is pointing to the same reference.

Suggestion: 
1. Replace Vector<> with List<> which is better in performance. 
2. In java the class name starts with first letter in upper case. Please change gridObject to GridObject.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
objectMatrix.addElement(objectVector);
System.out.println(objectMatrix.elementAt(0).size());
objectVector.clear();
```

Keep in mind that `objectVector` is a *reference*. So when you call `objectMatrix.addElement(objectVector);`, you're storing a *reference* to `objectVector` into `objectMatrix`. The actual object that that reference points to has not been copied or altered in any way.

Thus, when you call `objectVector.clear()`, you clear out the objet that `objectVector` points to, which also happens to be the object whose reference you most recently added to `objectMatrix`.

To solve this, either allocate a `new Vector()` for every iteration of your `while` loop or copy the contents of `objectVector()` into a `new Vector()` before adding it to `objectMatrix`.

On a side note, you probably should use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`. `Vector` is a legacy class which almost never needs to be used these days.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding objectVector to the objectMatrix - fine.
You are then clearing objectVector so the copy objectMatrix has of this has now been cleared also - not fine.

Why don't you instantiate the objectVector within the first while loop. e.g. like this:

```
lineReader = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
Vector<gridObject> objectVector = new Vector<gridObject>();
```

Then you don't need to clear this.